# How can I pass getSimpleRandomName () text available for all of the scenarios in a Feature file

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, gherkin, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I got a scenario where I need to pass a random getSimpleRandomName(textType) text need to available in Feature file. I am able to get random text attached to Automation Person for scenario 1.
How can I make the same text available for the rest of my scenarios?

```
import { Then, When, And } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";

Then("I type unique {string} in {string} field", (textType, textboxname) => {
  cy.getSimpleRandomName(textType).then(($value) => {
    cy.get("#content_container")
      .parent()
      .type($value);
  });
});


Feature: Create, Update
 
Background: 
  Given I open the build URL
  When I logged in as user "qa.team" 

Scenario: Create a new person
When I click on the left menu "People" > "Create New" > "Person"
And I should see "Person / New Person" page
And I type unique "Automation Person" in "* Person Name" field
Then I should see "Testing Automation Person-RedQwE" in the results table 

Scenario: Update existing person
When I click on the left menu "People" > "Open" > "Person"
And I should see "Person" page
And I type "Testing Automation Person-???" in search field  // how can I get the same text here ?
```

Comment: You can have a look at this thread. It might solve your issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63195796/passing-a-same-random-number-to-all-tests-in-cypress/63241225

Comment: In my BDD case, I am passing ‘string’ from feature file to Javascript step definition. I need to attach some random text to the string while creating the person scenario. Eg eg the text looks as follows: Automation Person- AcDgiw.This is working fine. But I need that created person text available in that step defenition file globally. so that I can use in update person scenario. In cypress-cucumber- preprocessir test how can I handle the case?